# Leave open a StreamReader in Unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, stream, streamreader

I am developing a game in which I need to retrieve data from a stream (that hasn't end).

I have a class called StreamingChannel which creates the streaming channel

```
    public StreamingChannel (){

    //stuff to set the stream

    webResponse = (HttpWebResponse) webRequest.GetResponse();
    responseStream = new StreamReader (webResponse.GetResponseStream (), encode);
    }
```

and to read from it i have this method

```
public string Read(){

    try{
        string jsonText = responseStream.ReadLine();
        return jsonText;
    }catch(ObjectDisposedException){
        return null;
    }
}
```

I perform the reading every tot secs with an InvokeRepeating and I do that for the whole game.

It works great except that for the fact that my stream lasts for about a couple of minute. After that it throws an ObjectDisposedException.

At first I wanted to restore the connection but I didn't manage to do that without reinstantiate the whole connection. In this case the problem is that the game lags for about a seconds. 
So how can I tell the StreamReader that has to leave open the channel?

ps I cannot use the constructor

```
public StreamReader(
Stream stream,
Encoding encoding,
bool detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks,
int bufferSize,
bool leaveOpen)
```

because it has been introduced in the version 4.5 of the .NET Framework, and Unity doesn't support that.

Comment: Are you sure it's the StreamReader that's disposed? What's returned if you call `ToString()` on the `ObjectDisposedException`?

Comment: Actually I am not really sure (I'm quite new at that). After some googling I came up with this conclusion. Anyway I added this instruction in the catch clause of the Read() method: Debug.Log("myself " + ToString() +   " webresponse " + webResponse.ToString() + " responsestream " + responseStream.ToString());                                                                       And the output is: myself null webresponse System.Net.HttpWebResponse responsestream System.IO.StreamReader

Comment: Change catch(ObjectDisposedException){ to catch(ObjectDisposedException e){ and add Debug.Log("exception: " + e) to your catch block.

Comment: It says: exception: System.ObjectDisposedException: The object was used after being disposed.

Comment: What about Debug.Log("stack: " + e.StackTrace)?

Comment: at System.Net.WebConnection.BeginRead (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request, System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, System.AsyncCallback cb, System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.BeginRead (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, System.AsyncCallback cb, System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) [0x00000] in

Comment: <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer () [0x00012] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/StreamReader.cs:338 
  at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLine () [0x0001b] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/StreamReader.cs:464 
  at StreamingChannel.Read () [0x00000] in .... (my files' path)

Comment: So StreamReader is not disposed, since disposal sets the internal Stream to null, but the call stack shows that the ReadLine call was passed on to the Stream. Looking at the Mono source, I'd guess that the WebConnection has been closed/disposed. Might the server have closed your connection because you're reading the WebResponse too slowly?

Comment: Thank you! Your observation made me think...and I have done some tests varying the frequency of the reading. Actually it seems there is a problem with the server that after a certain amount of data read closes the connection (I am using the streaming API of twitter). I need to figure out what the problem is... Anyway if I have to reconnect do you have any idea how to do that without make the game lag? I have tried with coroutines but all has been worthless...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A streaming API expects your code to pull data out of Stream pretty aggressively. You may not be able to wait for Unity to schedule your ReadLine method. I think a better model is to use a separate thread to pull data as fast as possible from the Stream and store it in a buffer. *(I think this is possible in Unity.)* Then you can pull the stream data out of your buffer in the standard Unity thread without worrying about the pull rate. A ConcurrentQueue would be a great buffer, but Unity doesn't support it, so I've used a locked List.

Using a separate thread also allows you to restart after failures without blocking the main game.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
public class StreamingChannel
{
    private readonly List<string> backgroundLinesList;
    private readonly object listLock = new object();
    private Thread streamReaderThread;

    public StreamingChannel()
    {
        streamReaderThread = new Thread(this.ReadWebStream);
        streamReaderThread.Start();
    }

    public List<string> Read()
    {
        if (!streamReaderThread.IsAlive)
        {
            streamReaderThread = new Thread(this.ReadWebStream);
            streamReaderThread.Start();
        }

        List<string> lines = null;
        lock (listLock)
        {
            if (backgroundLinesList != null)
            {
                lines = backgroundLinesList;
                backgroundLinesList = null;
            }
        }

        return lines;
    }

    private void ReadWebStream()
    {
        try
        {
            //stuff to set the stream
            HttpWebRequest webRequest;
            HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
            StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), encode);
            while (!responseStream.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = responseStream.ReadLine()
                lock (listLock)
                {
                    if (backgroundLinesList == null)
                    {
                        backgroundLinesList = new List<string>();
                    }
                    backgroundLinesList.Add(line);
                }
            }
            log.Debug("Stream closed");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.Debug("WebStream thread failure: " + e + " Stack: " + e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's strange because if I change the frequency by which I read from the stream (from 0.5 sec to 2 secs) the server closes the connection anyway. Moreover, when I use the 2 secs intervall it reads more lines (about 200) than in the 0.5 secs interval case (about 160)... That confuses me a bit... And, unfortunatelly, Unity doesnt' support your approach.

Comment: [Unity script reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/410/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoCompatibility.html) indicates .NET 4.0's ConcurrentQueue is not supported, so I've replaced it with a locked List<string>. Was there anything else in my code that Unity doesn't support?

Comment: According to [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/connecting), "Twitter will close a streaming connection ... [if] a client reads data too slowly. Every streaming connection is backed by a queue of messages to be sent to the client. If this queue grows too large over time, the connection will be closed." If this is the problem, the server-side queue will fill up at different times, depending on the server-side push rate.

Comment: Actually I found out that Unity isn't thread safe [link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/180243/threading-in-unity.html). What I tried to do is to simulate what you are doing and read from the stream really often (each 0.1secs) but what happens is that the streams blocks faster than before. That's why I continue to think that It's like I can read only a certain amount of data and then I need to restore the channel...Is that possible? How can I avoid that??

Comment: In that link, the point is that the *Unity API* is not thread safe, but you **can** start .NET threads for background work. That's exactly what this code is doing. The background thread never calls any Unity API functions. On the other hand, Twitter lists other reasons for closing a streaming connection. I'll read it again later today.

Comment: I tested your solution and the thread never starts (the function ReadWebStream is **never** called, neither in the constructor) after that I found that on the web. I read the Twitted documentation (even the list you're talking about), I'm going to check it again...

Comment: I always forget to call Thread.Start(). Just fixed my answer.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!! Now even if it needs to reconnect the game isn't affected! (Sorry I'm not really practical of threads).